# SIlverstripe <%loop AllChildren %> with Skeleton

Tags: frameworks, silverstripe

I'm using Skeleton for my 16 columns grid system on Silverstripe.
My code below:

```
<% loop $AllChildren %>
    <div class="three columns"><a href="$Link"><h5>$Title</h5></a></div>
<% end_loop %>
```

produces:

```
Children1   Children2   Children3   Children4   Children5
Children6   Children7   Children8   Children9   Children10
```

My question is how do I put a space between the rows so the output will 
be like:

```
Children1   Children2   Children3   Children4   Children5

Children6   Children7   Children8   Children9   Children10
```

Answer (score 2):

In SS3 you can use `$MultipleOf()` ([api docs](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-SSViewer_BasicIteratorSupport.html#_MultipleOf)) in your templates to output something every nth item, e.g.

```
<% loop $AllChildren %>
    <div class="three columns"><a href="$Link"><h5>$Title</h5></a></div>

    <% if $MultipleOf(5) %>
        <hr class="extra-space">
    <% end_if %>
<% end_loop %>
```

Comment: though this won't be very responsive... I'd use css for it as e.g. zurb fuoundation does it with the block-grid. This way you can have e.g. 1 item per row in mobile, 3 items per row in medium, 5 items on desktop etc...

Comment: How do I make it responsive using Skeleton framework? This way you can have e.g. 1 item per row in mobile, 3 items per row in medium, 5 items on desktop etc

Comment: well, that's a CSS issue. Depends on how you create your css you can have different helpers for css media queries. search for "responsive web design" to get more information. AFAIK silverstripe's simple theme has already some css file for different layouts, there you could put the css for mobile or tablet...

Comment: can you give example using zurb foundation block grid, I mean how do you put that inside the media query?

Comment: well, zurb is a full css framework (based on sass), it was just meant as an example. It uses the :nth-child() selector to make a linebreak, see https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child and http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html